# Running Different Data sets in a Loop in R

Tags: r, database, loops, variables, for-loop

I am attempting to run multiple years of a data set through a loop, 2009 to 2014 specifically, and renaming variables to reflect the year. For example, I am loading in `consolidated` from 2009, and trying to rename `$AGE09` to `$AGE`. To clarify: I would like to be able to do this with 2010, 2011, and so on -- I want to be able to run `consolidated.2009$AGE <- consolidated.2009$AGE09X`in a loop for all years, changing the 2009 to 2010, and 09 to 10, etc.

I am having a great deal of difficulty figuring out how to have R load a single year of data, rename the variable, and do to the other things I would like in a loop.

```
rx_files <- as.list(dir(pattern="* - rx.rda"))
consolidated_files <- as.list(dir(pattern="* - consolidated.rda"))
   for(i in c(2009:2014)){                                                             
     load(rx_files[[i]])
     load(consolidated_files[[i]])
     rx.[[i]] <- rx.[[i]]
     consolidated.[[i]] <- consolidated.[[i]]
     consolidated.2009$AGE <- consolidated.2009$AGE09X
     #I attempted to run the above code in the loop using the below code
     consolidated.[[i]]$AGE <- consolidated.[[i]]$AGE*X
   }
```

I continuously run into errors where R does does not identify`rx.[[i]]` or `consolidated.[[i]]` as a legitimate object. It is a difficult problem to explain, hopefully someone here may be able to offer assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few comments on your question:
when you call rx_files[[i]] with i == 2009 you're looking for the 2009th element of that list, I doubt this list starts at year 1, so you're probably not getting year 2009 by doing so.

When you do rx.[[i]] it seems you're trying to concatenate a name such as rx.2009. it doesn't work this way, [[ is used for lists rx. is not a list.

Please try this and let me know if it's what you want, I can then edit to explain.

```
library(data.table) # to use the function setnames, execute install.packages("data.table") if you don't have it
rx_files <- as.list(dir(pattern="* - rx.rda"))
consolidated_files <- as.list(dir(pattern="* - consolidated.rda"))
#supposing all these files start with a clean year (4 numeric characters) and that there's only one file per year and filetype
years_rx <- as.numeric(substr(rx_files,1,4)
years_cf <- as.numeric(substr(consolidated_files,1,4)
for(i in c(2009:2014)){                                                             
  load(rx_files[[which(years_rx == i)]]) # not used actually, why do you load it ?
  load(consolidated_files[[which(years_cf == i)]])
  eval(parse(text=sprintf("setnames(consolidated.%s,'AGE%sX','AGE')",i,substr(i,3,4))))
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this was extremely helpful. The code is now running and renaming the variables as hoped. To answer your previous point, I wrote some code to make the list the 2009th - 2014th elements in the list to simplify things, but thought it detracted from the point of my question.

Comment: Very good, tell me if you need me to explain some lines or if it's good enough as is, then consider validating the answer :)